# select from two tables and sum the values from one of the column and group by itemkey

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm just seeking for an assistance because i have been searching how to solve the c# mysql code. I have two tables, table for listing stock and the other one for monitoring sales.

```
SELECT 
    inventory.Item, 
    inventory.buyingPrice, 
    inventory.sellingPrice, 
    sales.ItemKey, 
    SUM(sales.QuantitySales) As Qsales 
FROM 
    sales 
    INNER JOIN inventory ON sales.ItemKey=inventory.ItemKey 
WHERE 
    sales.dateSales BETWEEN '2019/11/12' AND '2019/11/18'
GROUP BY 
    sales.ItemKey, 
    inventory.Item, 
    inventory.buyingPrice, 
    inventory.sellingPrice
```

**stock table**

```
| ItemKey    | ProductName | BuyingPrice | SellingPrice
----------------------------------------------------
| 1572661229 | blue band   | 20          | 30
| 1572661899 | salt        | 10          | 20
| 1572661234 | sugar       | 80          | 100
| 1572664312 | maize flour | 100         | 150
```

**Sales table**

```
| ItemKey    | QuantitySales | dateSales 
----------------------------------------------------
| 1572661229 | 2             | 2019/11/12   
| 1572661899 | 3             | 2019/11/17  
| 1572661234 | 4             | 2019/11/17    
| 1572664312 | 10            | 2019/11/17
| 1572661899 | 4             | 2019/11/18
| 1572661229 | 1             | 2019/11/17
| 1572664312 | 2             | 2019/11/18
| 1572661229 | 2             | 2019/11/18
```

What is displayed onto our data gridview

```
    | ItemKey    | Qtn | Product Name | Buying Price| Selling Price
    ----------------------------------------------------
    | 1572661229 | 25   |  blue band   | 20          | 30
    | 1572661899 | 35   |  salt        | 10          | 20
    | 1572661234 | 20   |  sugar       | 80          | 100
    | 1572664312 | 60   |  maize flour | 100         | 150
------------------------------------------------------------
    | TOTAL      | 140  |
```

What im expecting to be displayed onto our datagridview

```
    | ItemKey    | Qtn | Product Name | Buying Price| Selling Price
    ----------------------------------------------------
    | 1572661229 | 5   |  blue band   | 20          | 30
    | 1572661899 | 7   |  salt        | 10          | 20
    | 1572661234 | 4   |  sugar       | 80          | 100
    | 1572664312 | 12  |  maize flour | 100         | 150
------------------------------------------------------------
    | TOTAL      | 28  |
```

The code works fine on single date but when i retrieve data on the entire sales period, the data retrieved has been multiplied by a certain factor. kindly help me solve the above code

Entire Code

```
public void getSalesData(String date, DataGridView listV, String Seller, String[] SalesPeriod)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        listV.Rows.Clear();
        int bpTotal = 0;
        int spTotal = 0;
        int profit = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int qtnFinalTotal = 0;
        int bpFinalTotal = 0;
        int spFinalTotal = 0;
        int finalProfit = 0;
        String sql;

        if(string.Equals(Seller, "10")){
            sql = "SELECT inventory.Item, inventory.buyingPrice, inventory.sellingPrice, sales.ItemKey, SUM(sales.QuantitySales) As Qsales FROM sales INNER JOIN inventory ON sales.ItemKey=inventory.ItemKey WHERE sales.dateSales BETWEEN '" + SalesPeriod[0] + "' AND '" + SalesPeriod[1] + "' GROUP BY sales.ItemKey, inventory.Item, inventory.buyingPrice, inventory.sellingPrice";
            //sql = "SELECT MAX(inventory.Item) As Product, inventory.buyingPrice, inventory.sellingPrice, sales.ItemKey, SUM(sales.QuantitySales) As Qsales FROM sales INNER JOIN inventory ON sales.ItemKey=inventory.ItemKey WHERE sales.dateSales BETWEEN '" + SalesPeriod[0] + "' AND '" + SalesPeriod[1] + "' GROUP BY sales.ItemKey, inventory.buyingPrice, inventory.sellingPrice";
        }
        else
        {
            sql = "SELECT inventory.Item, inventory.buyingPrice, inventory.sellingPrice, sales.ItemKey, SUM(sales.QuantitySales) As Qsales FROM sales INNER JOIN inventory ON sales.ItemKey=inventory.ItemKey WHERE sales.dateSales BETWEEN '" + SalesPeriod[0] + "' AND '" + SalesPeriod[1] + "' AND inventory.date BETWEEN '" + SalesPeriod[0] + "' AND '" + SalesPeriod[1] + "' AND Sales.SellerId='" + Seller + "' GROUP BY sales.ItemKey, inventory.Item, inventory.buyingPrice, inventory.sellingPrice";
        }

        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow col in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = listV.Rows.Add();
                i++;

                listV.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = col["ItemKey"].ToString();
                listV.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = col["Item"].ToString();
                listV.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = col["Qsales"].ToString();
                listV.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = col["buyingPrice"].ToString();

                bpTotal = Convert.ToInt32(col["buyingPrice"]) * Convert.ToInt32(col["Qsales"]);
                listV.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = bpTotal.ToString();

                listV.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = col["sellingPrice"].ToString();

                spTotal =Convert.ToInt32(col["sellingPrice"]) * Convert.ToInt32(col["Qsales"]);
                listV.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = spTotal.ToString();

                profit = spTotal - bpTotal;

                listV.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = profit.ToString();

                qtnFinalTotal = qtnFinalTotal + Convert.ToInt32(col["Qsales"]);
                bpFinalTotal = bpFinalTotal + bpTotal;
                spFinalTotal = spFinalTotal + spTotal;
                finalProfit = spFinalTotal - bpFinalTotal;
            }

            listV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "TOTAL";
            listV.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = qtnFinalTotal.ToString();
            listV.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = bpFinalTotal.ToString();
            listV.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = spFinalTotal.ToString();
            listV.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = finalProfit.ToString();

            dt.Rows.Clear();

            //Add Styling
            listV.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
            listV.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
            dt.Rows.Clear();

            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked good and fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/968c23/3 , Could you give us more detail otherwise it look so good

Comment: Thanks for your reply, kindly i have viewed your answer and is awesome but you have left wHERE dateSales seletion

Comment: I'm just stranded because is still returning the same data with multiplying factor.. Check the edit

Comment: Hi D Shih, your code works fine but when i use c#, their is some misbehaving

Answer (score 0):

Hae thanks guys for those made a try on my question. finally i got an answer. I added a new column of date to stock table then i added the below line

```
AND sales.dateSales = inventory.date
```

changed from this

```
SELECT 
    inventory.Item, 
    inventory.buyingPrice, 
    inventory.sellingPrice, 
    sales.ItemKey, 
    SUM(sales.QuantitySales) As Qsales 
FROM 
    sales 
    INNER JOIN inventory ON sales.ItemKey=inventory.ItemKey 
WHERE 
    sales.dateSales BETWEEN '2019/11/12' AND '2019/11/18'
GROUP BY 
    sales.ItemKey, 
    inventory.Item, 
    inventory.buyingPrice, 
    inventory.sellingPrice
```

to this

```
    SELECT 
        inventory.Item, 
        inventory.buyingPrice, 
        inventory.sellingPrice, 
        sales.ItemKey, 
        SUM(sales.QuantitySales) As Qsales 
    FROM 
        sales 
        INNER JOIN inventory ON sales.ItemKey=inventory.ItemKey 
    WHERE 
        sales.dateSales BETWEEN '2019/11/12' AND '2019/11/18' AND sales.dateSales = inventory.date
    GROUP BY 
        sales.ItemKey, 
        inventory.Item, 
        inventory.buyingPrice,
        inventory.sellingPrice
```

and it worked well